# Which tool makes deployments of java applications on EC2 easier?

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, spring-boot, aws-opsworks

I have a (simple spring-boot) java application that I want to deploy and run on our ec2 platform. There is (apart from a custom EC2 solution) OpsWorks and Beanstalk, I *think* OpsWorks is the better fit because it is easier to extend.

Which tool fill best the gap between my user code and the ec2 platform? I want to:

- Be able to properly startup and shutdown my application, i.e. I want the usual Exit Hooks to run on application restart/stop/shutdown
- Notice when application startup fails. (Deploy should not be marked as successful or application shall no be healthy). I guess this part needs some preparation in my user code, so the container or run script can be notified once setup is successful.

The default Java config of OpsWorks adds an additional apache httpd in front of a tomcat. I don't like this additional component because it introduces additional parts you have to debug in case of errors (timeout configs for example).

So would you recommend a war or jar solution? Would you use OpsWorks? And if you use OpsWorks, do you use an additional layer/tool for managing the deployments?
The deployment must be possible on the command line (so I can automate alpha deploys with jenkins). Maven integration would be nice but is not required.

Answer (score 0):

If you want easy deployment of a Java or Spring Boot app on AWS, [Boxfuse](https://boxfuse.com) does what you want.

For you Spring Boot application you literally only have to execute:

```
boxfuse run my-springboot-app-1.0.jar -env=prod
```

This will

1. Create AMI with your application ready to boot
2. Create an Elastic IP or ELB with the health check url as defined in your Spring Boot config
3. Create a security group with the ports defined in your Spring Boot config
4. Create an auto-scaling group
5. Launch your instance(s)

Any subsequent update will be done as a zero downtime blue/green deployment.

All deployments automatically ensure the healthchecks pass before sending traffic to the new instances and taking the old version offline.

More info: https://boxfuse.com/getstarted/springboot

Disclaimer: I am the founder and CEO of Boxfuse

Comment: Sounds great. I'll give it a try.
BTW: You should have mentioned that you're the CEO of Boxfuse.

Comment: Good point. It's at the top of my profile, but I've now also added it to my answer. Thanks.